# .NET Core 2.1 with Angular 5 getting Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket, sockjs, handshake

When I run my .net core 2.1 Angular 5 template, I get the following error in chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:44356/sockjs-node/840/eaa2iary/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

The application fails to run in IE.

on expanding the error I get: WebSocketBrowserDriver    @   sockjs.js:1679

I searched around for a solution but all of them were related to ngnix or some other kind of set up.
The project was made using dotnet cli's angular template and no changes were made to the configuration. it was running fine when the template was first created. I had added few code but it is not related to any of the project set up files.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the "live reloading" on development mode.

use  "start": "ng serve --live-reload=false" in your package.json in "scripts"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this error is expected when using .net core 2.1 Visual Studio 2017 template

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1556

Answer (score 0):

In my view, spa.UseAngularCliServer() host angular in development mode, angular has a "live reloading" on development mode, so error appears.
Releated: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/383

Answer (score 0):

in your angular package.json Just use:

```
"start": "ng serve --public-host"
```